# Install Ubuntu on RasPI... using RasPI

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I installed Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi, and I'm wondering how I can install Ubuntu Core using only my Raspberry Pi. I don't have a computer that can read microSD cards other than the Pi, so I'm outta luck?

Comment: I don't have a machine that reads SD cards either, but cheap thumb-drive like devices that allow SD/microSDs to be inserted and then used as a thumb-drive are easy to find. They allow any device with a USB port to use SDs (and cost $1-$2 usually)

Answer (score 0):

Some models of Raspberry Pi can be booted from USB media. The [Raspberry Pi Foundation publishes a brief tutorial on their website](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#usb-mass-storage-boot) that explains how to do this.

Most of the Ubuntu installations you'll see in a Google search on the topic are for Ubuntu MATE. However, the Ubuntu website details a [procedure for installing Ubuntu Core... on an SD card.](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) However, if you'll follow the instructions & make the minor alterations required to write the Ubuntu Core image to a USB thumb drive instead of an SD card the procedure should work. However, please note that I have not actually done this myself, and so this qualifies only as "theory" for the moment.

One other thing to keep in mind: Raspberry Pi's Raspbian is configured to minimize wearout of the SD card. Ubuntu won't have that "built in", so you'll either need to set it up yourself, or accept reduced lifetime of the SD card.